# How to load files located On-Prem to AWS using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

Can I directly load files located in an On-Prem location to RDS using AWS GLUE?

Also if I have to park the files in an S3 before loading, what options do I have apart from using CLI?

Comment: What is the On prem storage medium that you have files in?

Comment: NAS Drive it is.

Comment: Did you resolve this by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out AWS Data Migration Service? In that you do not need AWS Glue.

If you prefer not to use AWS DMS, and go with S3, you can use S3 clients such as CloudBerry to move files from on-prem to S3, and use RDS commands, "Load data from S3...." to insert data into the RDS Tables (Only for MySQL) in AWS Glue script.

Please refer here for RDS COMMAND Load data from S3: [S3 to RDS MySQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can load s3 data to RDS using aws glue crawler and job.

But to load on premise data to s3 if your data is not that huge you can to use s3 file upload functionality via script or program, but if your data is too large then go for AWS Data Migration Service.